# Calculating Eigenvalues is only

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Assume that the following is used:

$$ 
A = \begin{pmatrix}
 0&  1&\\
 2&  3&\\ 
 4&  5&\\
 6&  7&\\
 8&  9& 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then calculating the Coveriance matrix, which, gives me:

$$ 
C = \begin{pmatrix}
 40&  40&\\
 40& 40&\\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then using the following:

$$
det = (a+b) \cdot (a+b)-4 \cdot(a \cdot b - c \cdot c),
$$

where in this case, $a = 40, b = 40, c = 40$ gives the answer:

$$
\lambda_{1} = 80, \\
\lambda_{2} = 0,
$$

These are therefore the correct Eigen values. However, using this formula, if I have the following:

$$ 
A = \begin{pmatrix}
 -4&  -2&\\
 -1&  -3&\\ 
 4&  5&\\
 6&  7&\\
 8&  9& 
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where the Covariance matrix is given:

$$
C = \begin{pmatrix}
 99.2&  103.4&\\
 103.4& 116.8&\\ 
\end{pmatrix},
$$

gives the Eigenvalues as:

$$
\lambda_{1} = 218.119 \\
\lambda_{2} = -15.5189
$$

When the actual values are:
$$
\lambda_{1} =211.774 \\
\lambda_{2} = 4.226
$$

Could anyone tell me where I am calculating this wrong please?

EDIT:

For
$\lambda_{1} = (a + b + det)/2 \\
 \lambda_{2} = (a + b - det)/2
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you double-checked your calculations? The eigenvalues of any $2\times2$ real symmetric matrix $\pmatrix{a&c\\ c&b}$ are given by
$$\frac{a+b\pm\sqrt{(a+b)^2-4(ab-c^2)}}2.$$
Plug in the entries of $C$, I don't find any discrepancies.

Comment: How do you mean "plug in the entries for $C$"? I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong.. Could it be the covariance matrix though?

Comment: That is weird.. It works when manually entering the numbers.. What could I be doing wrong? Ok, I'll check the code and get back to you :)

Comment: Thanks, I got it now :)! Quick question though.. Would the eignvectors therefore be.. `-($\lambda_{1}$ - a)` or, the highest eignvalue?

Comment: In our class, we are taught that you can extract the Eigen vectors from the values using: $l1 - a$ where $a$ is the first element in the matrix and $l1$ is the largest eigen value?

Comment: @Phorce I'm still not sure what you mean, but anyway, whenever $C$ is a $2\times2$ real symmetric matrix (whether it's a covariance matrix is unimportant) and $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are its two eigenvalues, then with $i\ne j$, any nonzero column vector of $\lambda_iI-A$ would be an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$.

Comment: If you get time, please could you make an example? I don't quite follow

Comment: @Phorce The $\lambda_iI-A$ in my previous comment contains a typo. It should read $\lambda_iI-C$. For instance, with your $C$, we have $\lambda_{\color{red}{2}}I-C=4.2262I-C=\pmatrix{-94.9738&-103.4000\\ -103.4000&-112.5738}$. Since its two columns are nonzero, they are both eigenvectors for $\lambda_{\color{red}{1}}$. You may verify that $C\pmatrix{-94.9738\\ -103.4000}=\lambda_1\pmatrix{-94.9738\\ -103.4000}$, for example.

Comment: Hey, so technically, it's just (4.2262 = C) (where C is the cov matrix?

Comment: @Phorce You earlier comments and the previous one make me think that you are perhaps using some uncommon notations. What do you mean by "4.2262=C"? Is the equality sign a typo or does it mean something other than an equality? At any rate, the two column vectors of $4.2262I-C$ are parallel to each other and they are eigenvectors for $\lambda_1$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14193/discussion-between-phorce-and-user1551)